# Redux saga - All-or-nothing cancellation - is spawning the correct approach?

Tags: javascript, redux, spawn, redux-saga

In my App I have a toggle which sends some data to the server when its value changes.
To ensure that the data is not sent too many times, I `debounce` the requests by 300 ms. Here is an example:

```js
function* watchChangeAction() {
    let task;
    while (true) {
        const action = yield take(actionTypes.CHANGE);
        if (task) {
            yield cancel(task);
        }
        task = yield fork(updateDataInServer, action);
    }

}

function* updateDataInServer(action) {
    try {
        // debounce 300 ms
        yield call(delay, 300);

       //retrieve key from the store
        const key = yield select(selectors.getKey);
        const newSettings = yield select(selectors.getSettingsItems);

        const response = yield call(serverSettings.update, newSettings, key);
        const responseKey = serverSelectors.getKey(response);
       // dispatch action with responseKey, which is stored for later use
        yield put(actions.saved(responseKey));

    } 
//...
 }
```

The issue is that **my server returns a distinct key in every response that it makes**. In order to be able to call the server, I must provide it the latest key in my request, which I maintain inside myStore (see above `const key = yield select(selectors.getKey)`).

The problem occurs when the cancellation is done after the request has been sent out but before the response from the server is received. 
What happens is that the request had already gone out (thus a new key has been provided), but by the time the response arrives the task is already cancelled, and thus the response key is never stored, and it is not possible to send any more requests.

After investigating the issue, I decided to go with `spawn` in order to ensure an all-or-nothing- approach. If the task is cancelled before the delay (priot to the request) then it will be ignored, however, if the request had occurred, the entire process will happen. So `updateDataInServer` now looks like this:

```js
 try {
      // debounce 300 ms
        yield call(delay, 300);

        const key = yield select(selectors.getKey);
        const newSettings = yield select(selectors.getSettingsItems);

         yield spawn(function*() {
               const response = yield call(serverSettings.update, newSettings, key);
               const responseKey = serverSelectors.getKey(response);
               yield put(actions.saved(responseKey));
        });

    } 
//...
```

Is this the correct approach?
I upgraded from version 0.95 to 0.13.0 just in order to get `spawn` because I could not find a different way to solve this issue. Can the behavior I want be achieved with that older version of `redux-saga`?

### ** Edit **

This approach actually does not work either. If the second call is made after 300 ms and before the response, I am facing the same situation of sending the server the wrong key. I found a way around it which is quite cumbersome and unclean (will share if someone is interested), but I wonder - isn't there an idiomatic approach to this type of *all-or-none* tasks in `redux-saga`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have a couple of requirements:

- calls to `updateDataInServer` should happen in sequence, so that the next call is able to use the token from the previous call
- calls to `updateDataInServer` should be throttled. If a call to `updateDataInServer` finishes and the user triggered the call again several times, only the last call should continue

I think redux-saga has just the right thing for this case. It offers something called an `actionChannel`. An `actionChannel` acts as a buffer, allowing you to handle the actions in sequence. By default, this would mean that all actions will be handled eventually, but by configuring it with a custom buffer you can control what happens with the actions that come in.

In the example below I've configured the channel with a sliding buffer of `1`. This means that if your saga is not ready to handle the next action (it's still busy with the call to `updateDataInServer`), it will queue one action. Every time a new action comes in it will bump the current action from the queue and replace it with the new action.

```
import { buffers } from 'redux-saga'
import { actionChannel } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* watchChangeAction() {
  const requestChannel = yield actionChannel((actionTypes.CHANGE, buffers.sliding(1));
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(requestChannel;
    task = yield call(updateDataInServer, action);
  }
}
```

[You can read more about channels here](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/Channels.html)

[And here's some more info about types of buffers](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/#buffers)